# can't compare value of variable that is inside class even if it is let global variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, variables

I need to compare a variable called '**let hours**' that is inside my class. Comparing needs to be performed in separate function called '**utcChange**' (after clicking a button). I thought, that if I declare this variable at the beginning as let it will be accessible anywhere. Why if statement inside **utcChange** function is not working?

```
let hours;

class Clock {
  el: Element;
  constructor(element) {
    this.el = element;
    setInterval(() => this.run(), 1000)
  }

  run() {
    var time = new Date();
    let hours = time.getHours()+utcValue;
    var hoursChanged = hours.toString();
    var minutes = time.getMinutes().toString();
    var seconds = time.getSeconds().toString();

    if (hoursChanged.length < 2) {
      hoursChanged = '0' + hoursChanged;
    }

    if (minutes.length < 2) {
      minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }

    if (seconds.length < 2) {
      seconds = '0' + seconds;
    }

    var clockStr = hours + ' : ' + minutes + ' : ' + seconds;

    this.el.textContent = clockStr;
  }
}

var clock = new Clock(document.getElementById('tsClock')); 
var utcButton = document.getElementById('button');
utcButton.addEventListener("click", utcChange);
var utcValue = 0

function utcChange(){

    if (hours < 23) {
        utcValue += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see that you are initializing this global variable. Can you also paste the error if any occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let hours` means the variable is only accessible from within the function it's defined in.

To use it from another function, make it a field.

Eg:

```
class Clock {
    hours: number;
    run() {
        this.hours = ...;
    }
}

function utcChange() {
    if (clock.hours < 23)
         // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your local variable in the `run` function of the class shadows the outer variable. Remove the `let` part from the declaration.

```
run() {
    var time = new Date();
    hours = time.getHours()+utcValue;
    var hoursChanged = hours.toString(); // Use without `let`
    var minutes = time.getMinutes().toString();
    var seconds = time.getSeconds().toString()
    ...
}
```

It will be better not to use the `glboal` variable. Make the variable as field, and use that field of the object to access the `hours`.